Comparison of proportions within one group but between two different questions: One-sample or two-sample z-test?
I have 300 participants who answered several questions in a questionnaire on a five-point Likert scale. I want to compare the proportion of the answers of either 1 or 2 with the proportion of the answers of either 4 or 5.

For the question "I would choose the burger," 50% answered 1 or 2 and 30% answered 4 or 5.
For the question "I would choose the pizza," 60% answered 1 or 2 and 25% answered 4 or 5.

Now, I want to compare the proportion of those who answered 4 or 5 on the burger question with the proportion who answered 4 or 5 on the pizza question, that is, 30% vs. 25%, to determine whether there is a statistically significant difference between said proportions.
Since the same participants answered both the question about the burger and the question about the pizza, my initial thought is that a one-sample proportion z-test might be appropriate. However, since the percentages being compared come from different questions in the questionnaire, I can't exclude the possibility that a two-sample proportion z-test might be more suitable.
Should I choose a one-sample proportion z-test or a two-sample proportion z-test?

Search here "McNemar's test".

The only information I have is the percentages that answered either 1-2, 3 or 4-5 on the Likert scale, and the size of the study population.
In light of this, is McNemar´s test still a better option than a sample proportion z-test?

Any test will need raw counts, not percentages.

I had an opportunity earlier to ask a statistician about comparing means of percentages from the same question (e.g., pizza question) from different studies (only knowing the percentages and sample size, i.e., exactly like in this situation), and he said that a two-sample proportion z-test (or chi-squared, as it is the same test) was fine to use. However, in this particular case, I don't know if a one-sample proportion (z-) test would do.

Neither.. You have two variables, both dichotomous (Yes = 4 or 5 in one, other score = No). Your situation is thus "two related samples". The test for it is McNemar's. It tests null hypothesis that frequencies in the cells 1,2 vs 2,1 of the 2x2 frequency cross-table are equal in the population.

To be exact, from answers on a Likert scale, where I know the proportions that answered either 1-2, 3 or 4-5 (as well ss the sample size(s)), I want to compare if the proportion of answers of 1-2 is different than the proportion of those who answered 4-5 (and vice versa(!). Before I looked at the data I was open for that either proportion could be greater than the other, so two-tailed, and not dichotomous data in the sense of the word in statistics that I understand, like in the usage of Chi-square). In light of this attempt to clarify, is McNemar still a given choice over z-test?

Welcome to CV @Bjorn.
The fundamental issue here is that you used a Likert scale. I know, it is very oftem used, published, etc. But the issue is that this is an ordinal scale, not an interval scale. Yes, people typically used "numbers" (1,2,3,4,5) to score the test, but these are not really "integer numbers". One could just as well (in fact it would be better) use (0,1,2,3,4), or (A,B,C,D,E). The issue is that $5-4 \ne 4-3 \ne 3-2 \ne 2-1$ etc. The distance between various scores is not preserved. Because of this, when using Likert scales, you can not perform any arithmetic on the scores; all you can do is compare them (when using "numbers" to code the scores, one can get lured into using arhitmetic; hence it would better to use (A,B,C,D,E) to code, thus avoiding this trap).
Now, if you had used a Visual Analog Scale (VAS), you could make a case for treating it as at least an interval scale, particularly if all the answers of a single subject are all on the same graph (because then the distance between answers can really be compared on an interval scale). VAS was initially used for pain score, but it can be just as well used for any subjective score, and avoid (many?, all?) of the pitfalls of a Likert scale. But that is a discussion for another post.
The good news is that you are not trying to do arhitmetic on your results; you are just trying to compare proportions (proportions of subjects who scored 4 or 5 on some question, based on your example).
You ask whether you can use a single sample proportion test, because the subjects are the same between the 2 questions. But that single sample is really the difference of scores; so that is arhitmetic, and no, you can not do that (if you had used a VAS, in fact, you could have done that, and gained more power).
However, there is still a way to kind of maintain some aspect of the parity, but with a two-sample test. For each subject, between the 2 questions, create an indicator variable which will be 1 if they scored the first question higher, 0 if the Likert scores are the same, and -1 if the second question has the higher score. Then compare the proportions of +1 to -1.
Or, indeed, run a 2 sample proportion test, comparing 90 out of 300 to 75 out of 300 (as in your example). That will tell you if the same subjects had higher/lower scores on a given question.
You propose to use a z-test (aka $\chi^2$). Given that your number of successes/failures are reasonably large, it will be an acceptable approximation. But you could also use a Fisher-exact test (based on the "exact" binomial distribution). Fwiw, using the data you gave as example (90/300 vs. 75/300), neither the z test (p=.17), nor the Fisher test (p=.2) are significant.
But you could use other tests than a test on proportions, including one specifically for ordinal data. You could use a Mann-Whitney U test (MWUt); see wiki here. This will test the null hypothesis that $P(burger>pizza)>.5$, that is, subjects rate the desirability of the burger higher than that of the pizza, statistically significantly more often. This is a good way to measure overall "preference" when using Likert (ordinal) data (because the MWUt only performs comparisons between scores). And it is better than just looking at the proportion of "high scores"; when doing that, you ignore all the other 3 scores (e.g. some questions could be more polarizing; they may get more high scores, but also more low scores, so that overall, there is really no strong preference). Btw, MWUt is a 2-sample test.
So TL;DR, you can only use 2-sample tests (because you can not compute difference of ordinal scores). And I would recommend the MWUt.

Thank you for your educational and comprehensive answer!

It would be nice (and polite) if those who down vote an answer at a minimum put their reasons in some comment.
